# How to wire/replace this bathroom light switch?

Tags: wiring, bathroom, switch, fans

I have a motion sensor switch controlling bathroom light and a single pole switch controlling exhaust fan in the same box. I want to replace the motion sensor switch with a single pole switch. 
Below is a link to the picture that shows how the wiring looks like in the box:

[image]

Basically, I have total 3 entry/exit points. 
White wires on all 3 are connected together.
Ground wires on all 3 are connected together.
Black wire from entry point 1 goes to a splitter input.At the output of splitter 1 black wire goes to a wire connector where the black wire from motion switch is connected. 2nd output of splitter is a black wire that goes to the bottom screw on single pole switch.
There is a red wire that goes to a wire connector where the black wire from entry/exit point 2 is connected.
The top screw on single pole switch is connected to a black wire that goes to the exit point 3.

So, now I want to replace the motion switch with single pole switch. How do I alter this wiring to put single pole switch?

Comment: There's no attached picture. Post a URL of the picture and someone will come along and edit in the actual picture.

Comment: I can't figure out why it does't let me attach picture. I have now included a picture link above.

Comment: Next time you need to add images, follow [these instructions](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/524/33), or use [imgur.com](http://imgur.com).

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off the power, and verify that it's off.
2. Remove the twist-on wire connectors that are connecting the motion sensor leads to the black wires.
3. Connect the black wires directly to the new single pole switch.
4. Install grounding conductors to the switches.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So after I add grounds to switches, there will be total of 5 ground wires going to the grounding connector. (3 from entry/exit points and 2 from switches). Correct?

Comment: @Hary yes, plus another to the box, if the box is metal. I like to twist the grounds together, and use a [crimp connector](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TSBEu.jpg) to hold them together. Especially when there's more than 3 or 4.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My box is plastic. I can use bare copper wire as ground. Right? Don't necessarily have to use a shielded wire. Correct?

Comment: @Hary Yes, bare copper can be used for grounding.